Giant wet patch appeared suddenly on wall and now filled with dark spots
Here is the image from the ground floor kitchen. This patch appears on wall between the two windows in the kitchen:

Here is what is on the other side of the wall. Please note that the black gutter and the black pipes are all newly installed around 6 months ago. This meant lot of new holes being drilled into the bricks. However, no wet patch appeared on the inside until now. Rain is common in the UK so I am not sure what is the actual reason for them appearing now.

Now similar but smaller patches are appearing on the first floor bedroom as well.
This is a circa 1900 semidetatched house in the UK. The patches appeared suddenly few weeks ago during very severe rain and have not gone away since. Overtime it has become more dark and has this yellow patches within it. I am not sure what I am supposed to do. Do I wait or do I call someone to have a look. If I call someone then who would that be.

No one has said this yet, but I would consider that wall socket, even when switched off, to be an electrical hazard. Make sure there's no possibility of a child standing on a chair to investigate a strange buzzing noise... Speaking from experience. I was that child!

Next time it rains go out and look at that gutter, the dark bricks look like it has been overflowing and pouring down the wall. Something is likely blocked, I think.

yes, that downspout is connected at the low-point of the gutter so a blockage would cause an overflow in this location.   the blockage may be in the gutter, or in the pipe

@matt_rule Yup - and in addition, if moisture gets into the socket, it could trip your fuse/RCD/RCBO. It may be worth getting an electrician in to disconnect the socket now, as the wall could take months to dry out, and will need redecorating anyway.

Why is there a gutter pipe coming out of the wall (under the small window)  ?

@nick The small pipe is a 'warning pipe' (aka overflow), probably from a toilet cistern. If the ballcock fails, not stopping inlet water, the excess overflows outside, not in your bathroom.

Yep, almost certainly an overflow.  (I've seen a very similar one from a cold-water tank in the loft.)

@nick, it is from the basin. The small window is the first floor bathroom.

Ah ok. Never seen waste/grey water and rain water mixed up like that.

@Machavity: the "drywall" tag is dubious, as the wall is probably plaster over brick. OP: can you confirm?

@nick: if it's from the toilet cistern, this will be clean water.

An update for everyone. So the people who installed the guttering near the roof came and had a look. Apparently moss had blocked the vertical pipe that was causing water build up which was then going into the space between the outer and inner walls. The guttering is cleaned but there is a lot of moss on the roof that needs to be cleaned. There is a rapidly increasing black spots and patch in the 1st floor bedroom. We are using the antimould spray but the room has become a lot colder as well. So much trouble because of the guttering getting blocked by moss.

It is evident that water has infiltrated the wall. It has not manifested itself until recently because it took some time to leach into the wall cavity. This can come from any or all of the drilled holes or possibly through the mortar between bricks. There may be cracked bricks as well. An examination is needed to determine the entry points.
The exterior need to be sealed and waterproofed.
The interior is showing the result of water. The black spots are mold.  You will need to have the wall opened and any damp insulation and any other materials removed and the framing given time to dry out.  When it is confirmed that there is no longer a moisture issue the wall can be closed.
Find a professional in your area that builds or renews exteriors. Or a general contractor as we have in the US. If you are not in charge of maintaining the building, alert the building manager.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

The new gutter installation is faulty, or clogged; any what way, there is a major leak on top that lets water flow down the wall. Looking at the damage, it is possible that it also comes onto the top or even down the inside of the brick wall. That a lot of water flows where it shouldn't is evident by the dark patch on the exterior wall running all the way from the gutter to the bottom of the image. That is the root cause and needs to be fixed asap because, as is obvious, the water seeps through into the interior, ruining interior walling and decoration and causing a mold issue. Over time, it also compromises the wall structure.
If there is interior insulation and drywall, that needs to be removed and discarded. Chances are that the water has flown much farther downwards, undetected, behind a drywall. If there is only solid plastering, it depends whether it has become brittle and soft. If so, it needs to be removed and replaced.
In any case, the mold is a serious health issue and must be dealt with immediately. A first aid measure is to use a chlorine solution. Many anti-mold fluids from home improvement stores are actually nothing but that, which can be easily self-made from chlorine bleach sold in those blue bottles available in drug stores, mixed with water. This arbitrary page has some good recommendations, except that I'd still use it on drywall as well; not as a permanent solution but until it can be removed. The main thing to observe is that chlorine itself is a health hazard as well — ventilate well so that you don't drive out the devil with the Beelzebub. Perhaps, especially if this is a sleep room or if one inhabitant has asthma or similar, consider using hydrogen peroxide. I also would not spray hydrogen peroxide or chlorine, even if that is the recommended way to apply it on those websites (what are they thinking?). Simply sponge it on, with rubber gloves, and only as a first aid.

There will be a plaster lining, no drywall or insulation boarding.

Mould is a serious health hazard, especially for anyone with breathing difficulties.


Black dots are mould.

Yellow spots are caused by water "dragging" material from the wall as it flows


I would suspect the new pipes and gutter. Not because of the new holes, but for leakage. It may have clogged during the heavy rain and soaked the wall. All in all, your case suggests poor installation or failure short after - get the pipes and gutters inspected, serviced or redone (covered by the one who installed the current ones).
Then you can start thinking of drying the wall, cleaning the moss and painting the wall.

It does seem like a clog but not sure yet, someone is coming over tomorrow morning.

You should not attempt to clean the moss (black mold). Replace the drywall. It is a health hazard.

@Philip As commented elsewhere, it is almost certainly not drywall; rather it's plaster over brick. Hence this answer is appropriate: you have to let the wall dry out, then assess what needs to be done.

Definitely the gutters. You can see the water-saturated brick (darker) going all the way up to the gutters in the second photo. I would surmise when the new downspout pipe was added to the gutters they created a leak into the brick wall.


The patches appeared suddenly few weeks ago during very severe rain and have not gone away since.

So water is getting in during rain.

Overtime it has become more dark and has this yellow patches within it.

Mold is growing.

I am not sure what I am supposed to do. Do I wait or do I call someone to have a look.

Waiting has proven detrimental, I advise against doing nothing twice.

The gutter is likely clogged at the top there and is causing a diversion of water into vulnerable spots.
Address the water infiltration issue first; start with a gutter cleaning.
Now for the inside of the house, that wall is a hazard and will have to be addressed.
Assuming it's plaster directly on brick? If so then chiseling off the plaster, killing the mold, applying new plaster, and painting should suffice

If you can blame the issue on improper gutter installation then all of these expenses could be covered by someone else but good luck with that route...

How do you rip out and replace a solid wall?

@gidds I'm not familiar with the construction of OP's specific wall. Is that merely plaster directly on brick? If so then chiseling off the plaster, killing the mold, and re-applying new plaster should suffice. Just do whatever the norm is for the wall in question.

@MonkeyZeus The OP tagged it as drywall.  Unless they think that's a tag for when you want your wall to be dry, I would assume it is drywall.  I'm curious how the wiring would be run if there's no space behind it. Original conduit? Would a building from that era in the UK have had wiring when built?

@JimmyJames Thanks, that was my assumption as well. Hoping gidds can shed some light as to why they're questioning is relevant.

Dollars to doughnuts, it's plaster directly onto brick in that age and style of house in the UK. The wall won't need replacing, but the plaster should be removed and wiring checked, imo.

@JimmyJames OP didn't tag it, someone else did. I agree with Jack that it's almost certainly plaster over brick.

Plaster which has got wet (soaked) is easily removable. Try to keep the mouldy rooms ventilated, even though this is probably impossible in the winter.

As already stated, the black is mould. You need to clean that with bleach, potentially sand down to remove all elements of mould, etc, and repaint the wall ONCE the problem is solved.
As for the actually problem, the obvious guess to me is the pipe installers have crossed the cavity. In UK homes you have effectively 2 walls next to each other. If someone has screwed a long screw spanning the cavity, then water on the outer wall will get to the inner wall and hence your problem. If they dropped debris down the cavity, again it would cause the same problem.
As others have suggested, there may be a blockage in the pipe which will make the outer wall wet as water saturates the outer wall, but again, unless the cavity is crossed with a screw or debris, I do not think you would get a problem as bad.
Maybe debris was already in the cavity, but a blocked pipe with water overflow is only showing it now.
As others have suggested, see what happens on the outside when it is chucking it down. See if there is an obvious water overflow.

The OP's wall is probablly not a cavity wall. Generally on a cavity wall each leaf is only single thickness so all the bricks are "stretchers" (long face visible), if you see "headers" (short face visible) then you are usually dealing with a solid wall two (or more( bricks thick.

Yeah, with that age and style of house in the UK, it's not likely to be a cavity wall.

A 1900 house almost certainly has not got a cavity wall.
The narrow pipe is an overflow pipe from the cold water tank and provided that this is not dripping in dry weather, this is not a problem.
The damp appears to originate from where the vertical pipe joins the gutter, so it seems likely that you have a blockage at this point.

It is possible that if you have moss on your tiled roof, that an unusually massive thunderstorm has flushed some of this moss into your gutters. In addition, normal roof tiles have a grit finish to them - which can slowly (over years) end up in the gutters.
